# Copy a file with python if that file already in another directory

Tags: python

I have jpg files in one directory and in another.
I want to copy the jpgs from directory "C:/from/" to directory "C:/to/" but only if the image file is present in the "from" folder and in the "to" folder OR in the subdirectiries in the "to" folder. If the image is not in the "to" folder/subfolders it should not be copied

Here is what I tried.
First I create 2 lists,from the "from" folder, with the full directories of each file and another with only the file names(code below).

```
import os
import shutil

fromDir = "C:/from/"
toDir = "C:/to/"
lstFolder = [] # create a empty list that will hold the full file path
lstFile = [] # create a empty list that will hold the file name only

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(fromDir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".jpg"):
        lstFolder.append(os.path.join(root, file))
        lstFile = [x.replace("C/from/","") for x in lstFolder]
```

That will give me a list like lstFolder==["C:/from/cow.jpg","C:/from/sheep.jpg","C:/from/chicken.jpg"]
and 
lstFile==["cow.jpg","sheep.jpg","chicken.jpg"]

Now if the "to" directory only have "cow.jpg" and "sheep.jpg" then the new image in the "from" directory should be copied.

Now I have tried to search in the "to" folder for the jpg name that is in lstFile(code below). But now I don't know what to do next, I have been stuck all day. Please help.

```
lstTo = [] # a list that will hold all the file names that is in lstFile
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(toDir):
    for jpgFile in lstFile:
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, jpgFile)
            lstTo.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

This will give me a list ["C:/to/beef/cow.jpg","C:/to/notbeef/sheep.jpg"] not containing file "chicken.jpg"

now I have tried some thing like the code below but with no results

```
for item in lstFile:
    shutil.copy2((x for x in lstFolder if item in x ),(y for y in lst2 if item in y ))
```

Thanks

Comment: Just some quick thougts: 1) don't create lstFile in the innermost loop each time. 2) Sets might be a more appropriate data type, and then you can do just `copyList = lstFile.intersection(lstTo)`

Comment: Cool thanks for the tips Jasper. I will try and see what I can do, I'm not a programmer, as you most likely can see from my messy code.